# Error sending data through Socket TCP / IP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

good afternoon.
I am trying to send a stream, via socket (elaborated in c #) to a websocket in javascript sent well with less data. I get an error that I do not know what is the following:

> "Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer."

## CODE

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(VarTransform.reciveMASKXOR(bytes));
string docs = SearhLucene((int)obj.SelectToken("point"),Obj.SelectToken("data").ToString());                                            bytes = VarTransform.sendMaskXOR(docs);
//ERROR############
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
//#################
```

## XOR coding

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            List<byte> Lbytes = new List<byte>();
            Lbytes.Add((byte)129);
            Lbytes.Add((byte)129);
            int Length = bytes.Length + 1;
            if (Length <= 125)
            {
                Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length));
                Lbytes.Add((byte)(Lbytes.Count));
            }
            else
            {
                if (Length >= 125 && Length <= 65535)
                {
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)126);
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 8));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)Length);
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)Lbytes.Count);
                }
                else
                {
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)127);
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 56));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 48));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 40));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 32));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 24));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 16));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)(Length >> 8));
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)Length);
                    Lbytes.Add((byte)Lbytes.Count);
                }
            }
            Lbytes.RemoveAt(0);
            Lbytes.AddRange(bytes);
            return Lbytes.ToArray();
```

## XOR decoding

```
byte b = buffer[1];
            int dataLength = 0;
            int totalLength = 0;
            int keyIndex = 0;
            if (b - 128 <= 125)
            {
                dataLength = b - 128;
                keyIndex = 2;
                totalLength = dataLength + 6;
            }
            if (b - 128 == 126)
            {
                dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
                keyIndex = 4;
                totalLength = dataLength + 8;
            }
            if (b - 128 == 127)
            {
                dataLength = (int)BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { buffer[9], buffer[8], buffer[7], buffer[6], buffer[5], buffer[4], buffer[3], buffer[2] }, 0);
                keyIndex = 10;
                totalLength = dataLength + 14;
            }
            if (totalLength > buffer.Length)
                throw new Exception("The buffer length is small than the data length");
            var key = new byte[] { buffer[keyIndex], buffer[keyIndex + 1], buffer[keyIndex + 2], buffer[keyIndex + 3] };
            int dataIndex = keyIndex + 4;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = dataIndex; i < totalLength; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ key[count % 4]);
                count++;
            }
            string res = "";
            try
            {
                res=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, dataIndex, dataLength);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                res = "all:a";
            }
            return res;
```

## FOUND

if docs value is `"hello"` (clean string no \n or \r or spaces)

## or

`"{'name':'newname'}"` (clean string no \n or \r or spaces)

## crash

if docs value `"    "` (spacesx4)

## error with

if docs value `"{'name':'newname'},{'name':'newname'},{'name':'newname'},..."`

with many values ​​fails, could be the XOR algorithm (is in C #)

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many, many, many, ... attempts I discovered the following so that this error does not happen:

**step 1** clean the character string like `\n \r \t` and separates (normalize so that they are not more than 4).

**step 2** does not exceed the 3 MB of data that is sent.

Thanks for your help and I hope this helps you (I will send images but I still can not)